# Yii2 как вывести из базы категории когда у них есть подкатегориии с подкатегориями?

Tags: php, yii2

Хочу вывести свои категории как на картинке, но запутался с foreach.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на картинке там есть 
1 Спойлер это названия категории
2 У категории есть подкатегория, то она без чекбокса, если у подкатегории есть свои подкатегории то они становятся чебоксами

Подскажите пожалуйста как это грамотно реализовать!

Пример хранения категорий в моей бд:

```
id | parent_id | title
 1 | 0 | Реклама
 2 | 0 | Автоуслуги
 3 | 1 | Настройка контекстной рекламы
 4 | 3 | SEO оптимизация сайта
 5 | 3 | Реклама в социальных сетях
 6 | 1 | Услуги промоутеров
 7 | 6 | Мерчендайзер
 9 | 6 | Промоутер в супермаркет
 10| 6 | Социологические опросы
 11| 2 | Кузовной ремонт
 12| 2 | Эвакуатор
 13| 2 | Зарядка аккумулятора
...|...| ..........................
```

Как я хочу чтобы было

```
1menu
 - menu
      - menu
      - menu
 - menu
      - menu
      - menu
2menu
 - menu
      - menu
      - menu
 - menu
      - menu
      - menu
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
```

namespace app\components;
use yii\base\Widget;
use app\models\Category;

class MenuWidget extends Widget{

```
public $tpl;
public $data;
public $tree;
public $menuHtml;

public function init(){
    parent::init();
    if( $this->tpl === null ){
        $this->tpl = 'menu';
    }
    $this->tpl .= '.php';
}

public function run(){
    $this->data = Category::find()->indexBy('id')->asArray()->all();
    $this->tree = $this->getTree();
    $this->menuHtml = $this->getMenuHtml($this->tree);
    return $this->menuHtml;
}

protected function getTree(){
    $tree = [];
    foreach ($this->data as $id=>&$node) {
        if (!$node['parent_id'])
            $tree[$id] = &$node;
        else
            $this->data[$node['parent_id']]['childs'][$node['id']] = &$node;
    }
    return $tree;
}

protected function getMenuHtml($tree){
    $str = '';
    foreach ($tree as $category) {
        $str .= $this->catToTemplate($category);
    }
    return $str;
}

protected function catToTemplate($category){
    ob_start();
    include __DIR__ . '/menu_tpl/' . $this->tpl;
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

}

Comment: ну и как мне реализовать твой виджет на примере картинки

Comment: так уже все сделано! код стоит вам дерево, вам нужно только вывести его.  посмотрите что возравщает метод...

Comment: а как вывести его правильно во view???

Comment: в методе инит проверяется , есть ли пользовательский параметр. если нет то используем вью menu  - в своство tpl записывается название файла вью. в методе catToTemplate подключается данный шаблон , и в шаблоне можете использовать переданный в метод параметр

Comment: я конечно извиняюсь за свою тупость, а можно пример

Comment: вы закидываете это в папочку виджет или компонеты. создаете там папку рядом menu_tpl   в ней создаете файл menu.php . в основном шаблоне подключаете виджет. и вызываете в нужном месте.   в файле menu.php работаете с $category и выводите как вам нравится

Comment: в components я создал файл CategoryWidget.php, потом создал папку category_tpl, а в ней файл category.php, потом во вview делаю вывод <?= CategoryWidget::widget(['tpl' => 'category']) ?>
Но выводит не так как надо и как мне сделать категории второго уровня жирным, а категории третьего уровня чекбоксами??

Comment: вы можете в массив добавить индификатор уровня, и основываясь на нем делать операции в выводе

Comment: не понимаю.........можно ваш скайп?

Comment: вы во вьюхе можете ввести переменную и автоинкрементировать ее, это будет индификатор уровня

Comment: можете показать примером, как бы правильно разложить по полочкам?!

Comment: вы можете использовать типа такой функции, где ключ уровень  вложенности     public static function builTreeDown2(array $user_ids, $level = 1, $level_users = [])
    {

        $users = User::find()->where(['referral' => $user_ids])->all();

        if ($users) {
            $level_users[$level] = $users;
            $ids = [];
            foreach ($users as $u) {
                $ids[] = $u->id;
            }
            $level_users = self::builTreeDown2($ids, $level + 1, $level_users);
        }

        return $level_users;
    }

Comment: не фига не понятно............тогда зачем виджет????

я решил по другому пути идти, но тут не получается третий уровень вытащить, вот пример кода, надеюсь поможете, знаю что ЗАДОЛБАЛ)

вот ссылка
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/643072/yii2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E

и еще я сдела в категории виртуальное свойство public $childs;

Answer (score 0):

надо познать суть рекурсии и построения ей дерева. Для yii есть пример http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=14520 Кратко суть показана в [Как правильно реализовать построение древа через рекурсию?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/378630/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8E)

Comment: Блин я понять не могу в модели у меня есть метод
    public static function getCategory()
    {
        $category = Category::find()->asArray()->all();
    }

сможете мне помочь???