# Yii2 рекурсия древовидного меню

Tags: php, yii2

Всем доброй ночи!

Помогите правильно вывести третий вложенный список во View

Model

```
    protected function buildTree($data, $rootID = 0)
{
    $tree = [];
    foreach ($data as $id => $node) {
        if ($node->parent_id == $rootID) {
            unset($data[$id]);
            $node->childs = $this->buildTree($data, $node->id);
            $tree[] = $node;
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}

public function getTree()
{
    $data = Category::find()->all();
    return $this->buildTree($data);
}
```

Controller

```
    public function actionProfile()
{
   ....code
    $tree = $model->getTree();
   ....code        

    return $this->render('profile', ['tree' => $tree]);
}
```

View

```
foreach ($tree as $item) {
echo '<br><br>' . $item->title . '<br>';

if (count($item->childs) > 0) {
    foreach ($item->childs as $child) {
        echo '----- ' . $child->title . '</b><br>';
    }
}
}
```

Получается так:

```
Категория
     ----- Категория
     ----- Категория
     ----- Категория
     ----- Категория
```

А надо вот так:

```
Категория
     ----- Категория
           ----- Категория
           ----- Категория
           ----- Категория
     ----- Категория
           ----- Категория
           ----- Категория
           ----- Категория
     ----- Категория
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте цикл вывода категорий заменить на этот код:

```
function showTree($tree,$space=4,$tab='') {
    foreach ($tree as $item) {
        echo '<br><br>' . str_repeat('&nbsp;',$space). $tab . $item->title . '<br>';

        if (count($item->childs) > 0) {
            showTree($item->childs, $space*2, ' ---- ');
        }
    }
}


showTree($tree);
```

Comment: Не работает так, мне обязательно надо выводить категории в view, что бы потом можно было из них сделать чекбоксы, поэтому я и делаю во view foreach!

Comment: Кто поможет мне с решением!!!!!!!!!!!!???

Comment: так вставьте этот код во view, и замените на нужные вам чекбоксы.
Массив tree возвращается из контроллера, во вьюшке берёте этот массив и проганяете через функцию showTree. Рад посмотреть также на другое решение

Comment: Вы имеете виду вставить function showTree во view???

Comment: ваш код подошел.....но у меня теперь другая проблема, а как сделать 3-й уровень вложенности чекбоксами??
Вот пример картинки
http://radikal.ru/lfp/s019.radikal.ru/i603/1703/ed/ddcad203212d.png/htm